# rvest: get all between two headline

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to get all text between two h2 headlines. I was able to get the two headline I wanted but I'm stuck now selecting the specific content between them.

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midway_Atoll")

headlines <- html_nodes(page, "h2")
x <- grep(pattern= "Contents", x=as.character(headlines))
headlines <- headlines[x:(x+1)]
```

Not sure if I'm missing the point of rvest but there must be a way to do this in two steps (get headline I want, then get the 'li' entries underneath).

Comment: I'am not exactly sure what you want? Is it each item in the table of content?

Comment: I I've understood correctly than you could do something like this: `body_text <- page %>%
  html_nodes("#mw-content-text") %>% 
  html_text()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood you correctly you want the text that follows the headline.
So the result should be a character vector with one element per `h2` heading.

E.g. the second being the text after **Location**, so

> As its name suggests, Midway is roughly equidistant between North
>   America and Asia, and lies almost halfway around the world
>   longitudinally from Greenwich, UK. It is near the northwestern end of
>   the Hawaiian archipelago, about one-third of the way from Honolulu,
>   Hawaii, to Tokyo, Japan.
>
> Midway Atoll is less than 140 nautical miles (259 km; 161 mi) east of
>   the International Date Line, about 2,800 nautical miles (5,200 km;
>   3,200 mi) west of San Francisco, and 2,200 nautical miles (4,100 km;
>   2,500 mi) east of Tokyo.

This can be done using *xpath* `preceding-sibling` as follows:

```
require(rvest)
require(purrr)
page <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midway_Atoll")

# Make sure you scope on the content of the website
content <- html_node(page, "#mw-content-text")
# Select the h2 headings, we need to know how much there are
headlines <- html_nodes(content, "h2")

# The following xpath looks at all nodes within the content and 
# counts how much of the preceding ones are h2-tags.
# For the Location text we want all nodes that have 1 preceding H2 tags
# namely "Location" itself. "Contents" (the heading of the TOC) does
# not count as it is nested. So no direct child of content.
# This xpath only selects p-tags look at the P.S.: to select all tags 
# within a paragraph

xpath <- sprintf("./p[count(preceding-sibling::h2)=%d]", seq_along(headlines)-1)

map(xpath, ~html_nodes(x = content, xpath = .x)) %>% # Get the text inside the headlines
  map(html_text, trim = TRUE) %>% # get per node in between
  map_chr(paste, collapse = "\n") %>% # collapse the text inbetween
  set_names(headlines %>% html_node("span") %>% html_text())
```

The results looks as follows:

```
                                      <NA> 
"Midway Atoll (/ˈmɪdweɪ/; also called Mid" 
                                  Location 
"As its name suggests, Midway is roughly " 
                     Geography and geology 
"Midway Atoll is part of a chain of volca"
```

**P.S.: An alternative**

```
# The not(local-name() = 'h2') makes sure that we only get "non h2" nodes

xpath <- sprintf("./*[count(preceding-sibling::h2)=%d and not(local-name() = 'h2')]", 
                     seq_along(headlines)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks! this looks good. But I get the error "could not find function "map"" are you using another package besides rvest here?

Comment: @JonGrub, just updated my answer. Sorry. `map` comes from the `purrr` package and is an improved version of the `*apply` family

Answer (score 1):

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midway_Atoll")
list<-html_nodes(page,css=".toctext") %>% html_text()
```